# How to force parse request body as plain text instead of json in Express?

Tags: node.js, json, express, content-type, node.js-connect

I am using nodejs + Express (v3) like this:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.route('/some/route', function(req, res) {
  var text = req.body; // I expect text to be a string but it is a JSON
});
```

I checked the request headers and the content-type is missing. Even if "Content-Type" is "text/plain" it is parsing as JSON it seems.

Is there anyway to tell the middleware to always parse the body as a plain text string instead of as json? Earlier versions of `req` used to have `req.rawBody` that would get around this issue but now it does not anymore.

What is the easiest way to force parsing of the body as plain text/string in Express?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you remove the use of the `bodyParser()` middleware, it should be text. You can view the `bodyParser` docs for more info: http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/middleware-bodyParser.html

Remove this line:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

#### EDIT:

Looks like you're right. You can create your own `rawBody` middleware in the meantime. However, you still need to disable the `bodyParser()`. Note: `req.body` will still be `undefined`.

Here is a demo:

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')
  , util = require('util');

var app = express();

function rawBody(req, res, next) {
  req.setEncoding('utf8');
  req.rawBody = '';
  req.on('data', function(chunk) {
    req.rawBody += chunk;
  });
  req.on('end', function(){
    next();
  });
}

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.use(rawBody);
  //app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
});

app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.is('text/*'));
  console.log(req.is('json'));
  console.log('RB: ' + req.rawBody);
  console.log('B: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
  res.send('got it');
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

**test.js**

```
var request = require('request');

request({
  method: 'POST',
  uri: 'http://localhost:3000/test',
  body: {'msg': 'secret'},
  json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('code: '+ response.statusCode);
  console.log(body);
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is I remove that line, ```req.body``` is undefined.

Comment: That works - accepting your answer. Looks like since the formidable multi-part change they did not bother reimplementing rawBody in Express 3. I wonder if there is already a library that does those 7 lines of code for me...

Comment: Any known methods to still have access to bodyParser and rawBody output?

Comment: This is GENIUS!!!  your `rawBody` function worked where all others failed!
Note to others: This makes the received string available on `req.rawBody` (NOT `req.body`).
I tried `body-parser` and `express.text()` both with and without the NPM `cors` package, all of which failed to return a simple string.

Comment: Nice solutions, but careful with that code when including this code as a middleware (tested express version 4.17.1), curl -X POST "myuri" -d "sdfsdf" => we never go in the on(data) or on(end) handler and it make the server hang (seems to be content-type relative).

Answer (score 52):

By default `bodyParser.text()` handles only text/plain. Change the type options to include `*/json` or `*/*`.

```
app.use('/some/route', bodyParser.text({type: '*/*'}), function(req, res) {
  var text = req.body; // I expect text to be a string but it is a JSON
});

//or more generally:
app.use(bodyParser.text({type:"*/*"}));
```

You can find the docs [here](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#type-2)

Comment: was using `application/text` instead of `text/plain`. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Is there a way so tell `bodyParser` not to generate an empty object body when there is no body in the request?

Comment: Would parsing json with `.text()` even work? Isn't that what `.json()` is for?

Comment: This is the real answer to the question

Answer (score 41):

In express 4.x you can use the text parser from bodyParser
https://www.npmjs.org/package/body-parser

just add in app.js

```
app.use(bodyParser.text());
```

Also in the desired route

```
router.all('/',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);

})
```

Answer (score 25):

Express understands by content-type how to decode a body.
It must have specific decoders in middlewares, which is embedded into the library from **4.x**:

```
app.use(express.text())
app.use(express.json())
```

Comment: , but I'm pretty sure these middle-wares were only added to the package in **v4.16.0** and later versions: https://github.com/expressjs/express/releases/tag/4.16.0

Answer (score 4):

**Two important things to achieve this.**

1. You need to add the text middleware in order to process text in the body
2. You need to set the content type by adding the right header "Content-type: text/plain" in the request

Here is the sample code for both.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
//This is the needed text parser middleware 
app.use(bodyParser.text()); 

app.post('/api/health/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.body);
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on ${port} ${new Date(Date.now())}`));
```

Save this as index.js.

Install dependencies.

```
npm i -S express 
npm i -S body-parser
```

Run it.

```
node index.js
```

Now send a request to it.

```
curl -s -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/plain" -d 'Any text or  json or whatever {"key":value}' 'localhost:3000/api/health'
```

You should be able to see it sending back whatever you posted.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the plainTextParser (https://www.npmjs.com/package/plaintextparser) middleware..

```
let plainTextParser = require('plainTextParser');
app.use(plainTextParser());
```

or

```
app.post(YOUR_ROUTE, plainTextParser, function(req, res) {             
  let text = req.text;

  //DO SOMETHING....
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I did it:

```
router.route('/')
.post(function(req,res){
    var chunk = '';

    req.on('data', function(data){
        chunk += data; // here you get your raw data.
    })        

    req.on('end', function(){

        console.log(chunk); //just show in console
    })
    res.send(null);

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the version of express and bodyParser has been upgraded to the appropriate versions. 
Express ˜4.x and bodyParser ˜1.18.x. That should do it. With that in place the following should work

> app.use(bodyParser.text());