# Body of request comes back as object when sending string request using $http.post (angular) and bodyparser.text()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, express, post

When I send a string value as the request, the req.body value is an object. I am using:

I have a factory cust1_service.postQuery:

```
.factory('cust1_service', function($http){
    return {
        postQuery : function(request){
            console.log('cust1 req : ' + request);
            console.log('typeof request : ' + typeof request);
            var config = {'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'};
            return $http.post('/cust1', request);
        }
    }
```

Here is how I call the factory in my controller:

```
cust1_service.postQuery(req_string).success(handleSuccess);
```

I am also using bodyParser.text() before my routes

```
var express = require('express'),   
config = require('./config/config'),    
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),    
api = require('./app/routes/api.js');               

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.text({   
    type: "text/*"               
}));                             

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));     //Serve static assets

require('./app/routes/api.js')(app, db);

app.listen(config.port, function() {    
    console.log('Listening on ' + config.port); 
})
```

So....when I get to my routing api

```
app.route('/cust1')
    .post(function(req,res){
            console.log('this is req.body : ' + req.body);
```

req.body is [object Object]...am I sending the request as a text type incorrectly?? I need req.body to be a string.

Answer (score 1):

Try to "`stringify`" the `req.body` to be sure if it's still passed as a `JSON` object. You can also try logging the console like `console.log('this is req.body : ', req.body,  ' --- ');`

One solution you can try is to completely remove the use of the `BodyParser` middleware - this should force the body to be text.
SO you need to remove or comment out the line:

```
app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: "text/*"}))
```

You can look at a closely related question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345166/how-to-force-parse-request-body-as-plain-text-instead-of-json-in-express)

I hope this helps;