# How to extract req.body on the server side (I'm using fetch)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm making a project that consists of separate frontend and backend. From the frontend, I make a POST request via fetch that should send a string 'ORANGE' to the backend and then the backend should log it to the console. I can't get the backend to console log the string. I looked at the request in devtools and the string 'ORANGE' was buried there under 'Request payload'. The request itself was sent alright. How do I actually access the string so I can do things with it? (eg, store in database)

```
//FRONTEND
const commentForm = document.getElementById("editform");
commentForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/posts/:id', {
        mode: 'cors',
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"
        },
        body: "ORANGE"
    }).then(function(response) {
        if (response.ok) {
            console.log("response.ok was true: "+ response)
        } else {
            let error = new Error(response.statusText)
            error.response = response
            throw error
        }
    })
});

//BACKEND
router.post('/posts/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('What do I put here to get ORANGE logged?!')
    //On the server side I tried some console.log tests.
    //console.log("req is " + req);               //req is [object Object]
    //console.log("type of req is " + typeof req); //type of req is object
    //console.log(JSON.parse(req)); //SyntaxError: unexpected token o in JSON at position 1  
    res.send('whatever. I want ORANGE.')
}
```

Comment: What about `console.log(req.body)`??

Comment: req.body is undefined

Comment: Express used to have a rawBody property on requests, but that's been removed, and now all request bodies are expected to be in JSON. If you want to send plain-text bodies, you'll have to implement your own middleware, as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12345876/2444210

Comment: you need to replace :id in http://localhost:3000/posts/:id with an actual id.

Comment: @jperl That will be necessary once the route does anything with that parameter, but that's not stopping the body from being available; it'll just bind req.params.id to the string `:id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Express 4.16 body-parser module isn't necessary anymore. All you need for getting the body is:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
```

Use `"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` inside the fetch otherwise CORS will send preflights and give you a hard time. (for more on this google CORS simple request requirements).

Answer (score 0):

Try for the following:

1. Use body parser in your server.js file.
2. Send post request as `content-type` as `json` as follows,

   `headers: { Content-Type: application/json }`

and body should be a JSON

`body: {"color":"ORANGE"}`

3. In your route just print

   `console.log(req.body.color)`

Answer (score 0):

Express won't, by default, process the body of a request. You need to load a module to do so explicitly.

Since you are using plain text, you can use the body-parser module. This will create a `body` property on the request:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
router.use(bodyParser.text({type: 'text/plain'}))
router.post('/posts/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send('Response')
});
```

Note, however, that it is generally better to use a structured data format like JSON rather than plain text.

Answer (score -1):

As in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) of fetch() explained:

> This is just an HTTP response, not the actual JSON. To extract the JSON body 
>   content from the response, we use the json() method (defined on the Body mixin, 
>   which is implemented by both the Request and Response objects.)

```
const response = await fetch('http://example.com/movies.json');
const myJson = await response.json();
console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
```

so you don't have a body object inside your response, only a json object, which is your body.