# How to parse request body?

Tags: node.js, express

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(cors())

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.all('/hello/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({
    'message': 'test',
    'x-result': req.headers['x-test'],
    'x-body': req.body
  })
})

app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 3000')
})
```

Request:

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/hello/' -d 'it is body' -H 'x-test: test'
```

And I want get this:

> { "message":"test", "x-result":"test", "x-body":"it is body" }

But instead I got this:

> {"message":"test","x-result":"test","x-body":{"it is body":""}}

Why and how do the right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force parse request body as plain text instead of json in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345166/how-to-force-parse-request-body-as-plain-text-instead-of-json-in-express)

Comment: @tbking 

bodyparser is deprecated;

app.use(express.text())
app.use(express.json())
- doesnt work, only app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })) got this body;

plain text show this after install - Cannot find module 'plainTextParser'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send the correct content type which in your case is `text/plain`.

```sh
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/hello/' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' -d 'it is body' -H 'x-test: test'
```

Along with the correct content type, you would want to use `express.text()` in the application.

```js
app.use(express.text())
```

Comment: Can I set default request content-type to 'text/plain' to omit "-H 'content-type: text/plain;'"?

Comment: If you use, `express.text()` only, and not the other types, the Express will parse the request as `text/plain` without the `content-type` header

Comment: @aaltw if this answered your question, can you mark it the best answer?