# How to parse JSON assigned to a variable in POST request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to set a webhook for a payment system. Although, they keep sending invalid JSON data with content-type "application/json" headers.

Since I have set express with `app.use(express.json())`, whenever they make a POST request I'm unable to parse the data and the server errors.

This is what they're trying to send:

```
data={
  "return": {
    "orders": [
      {
        "order": {}
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see: it's JSON content assigned to a variable.

How do I deal with that, in order to have access to the actual JS object?

Comment: Is the variable always `data=`? You can read the body as text, remove that prefix, then call `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: @Barmar yes, it's always data. Can you answer this question with this solution?

Comment: `body = body.replace(/^data=/, ''); data = JSON.parse(body);`

Comment: Have you tried contacting their tech support to find out how other customers process this webhook? It seems very unlikely that they don't provide a way to send normal JSON.

Comment: @Barmar they can send JSON, JSON (urlenconded) and XML

Comment: @Barmar this solution combined with yours has worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30099608/14172634

Comment: @Barmar you're amazing